# my csv import is not formatting the dates

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, mysqli

I cannot seem to get the csv file to format the dates to UTC time on import to mysql. Here is my query and if i take out the sql variables and the set statement it imports the information fine but i need the dates to be formatted in utc time.

```
$query = "
        LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE instructions
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        (route_name,stop_sequence_number,stop_location_id,stop_action,@stop_arrival_time,@stop_departure_time,time_zone);
        SET stop_arrival_time = STR_TO_DATE(@stop_arrival_time, '%m/%e/%Y %r');
        SET stop_departure_time = STR_TO_DATE(@stop_departure_time, '%m/%e/%Y %r');
        ";
```

Am I not using the STR_TO_DATE format correctly? i looked at the information on the format and it said that %m for numbered month, %e for single digit day, %y for four length year and the %r for AM - PM time.

Comment: It wont import it at all i get this error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET stop_arrival_time = STR_TO_DATE(@stop_arrival_time, '%m/%e/%Y'); SET stop' at line 5. When i get rid of the formating part it imports everything but the dates and im not sure why. it just inserts all 0's

Comment: can you show us a few rows of the csv

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to convert the string to a date in order to import the date.  As you have noticed it will except the statement after you have removed the STR_TO_DATE part of the import statement.  However, you will instead get a bunch of columns looking like `0000-00-00` because mysql does not understand dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, etc... Mysql only excepts dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

You can change this in Excel before doing your import.

In order to change the date format in excel: right click on the top cell. Choose `format cells` from the drop down list. change the `local` to something like `'Afrikans'`. Choose the format that looks like `2001-03-14`. Use the top cell to `fill down`. Then save the document.

Just a quick note: Excel sometimes tries to do too much and will revert this column back to a the `English(U.S)` default time zone. So, if you plan on doing more editing make sure that the column has not reverted back.

Here is a link to more string literals on [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

This stored procedure and post might help you as well: [Error code 1292](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108606/error-code-1292-mysql-datetime)

### Edit:

Alex, your code has 3 semi-colons in it. Have you tried your original code as shown by you without the first two but keeping the last? As such it would be consistent with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8164237/1816093) Answer.

Comment: The only problem with that is that it is a text file not on excel. I cannot change the column itself in the file its an upload to set delivery times there are hundred of rows. I understand why its not uploading into the tables now. but how can i get it to format the columns before the insert?

Comment: if the text file is formatted like a csv file type you can open it in excel...if you do not want to go that route then import as a VARCHAR into a raw table and use the stored procedure as an example to write one that will conform to what you need or even php if you prefer...